# Large HTML5 Canvas taking 400-500ms per frame to render from p5.js. Is this a limitation of the library?

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas, p5.js

Let me start by saying that I am not sure if a solution even exists, but it would be great if I could find one.

I am doing a school project to model the solar system. There was no specific requirement that things be even remotely to scale, but seeing as I am a bit more advanced than the other students (and a bit of a space enthusiast) I decided to challenge myself.

We are required to use the Processing.js or p5.js libraries for our graphics rendering, and when I tried to load a large canvas (browser width x 13000px), it took up a significant amount of system resources and caused the framerate to drop near 2-3 fps.

Its worth noting that this problem does NOT arise on any machine with a discrete GPU, but as this project is for class, I would like to optimize it to run in any browser, even on lower powered machines.

[A screenshot of my chrome dev tools performance tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwmIO.png)

[image]

and the code in question:

```
let sun, mercury, venus, earth, mun, mars, ab1, ab2, ab3, jupiter, io, europa, ganymede, callisto, saturn, satRings, uranus, urRings, neptune, nepRings;
const mid = window.innerWidth/2;
const scale = 6000;
let stopper = 1;
let stuff = [];
function setup() {//all distance and diameter inputs are the real-world measurements in km
  createCanvas(mid*2, 13000);
  stuff.push(sun      = new Sun(1392684, 'yellow', 'The Sun'));
  stuff.push(mercury  = new Planet(sun,57909000,  4880, 'brown', 88, 'Mercury', 0.2056));
  stuff.push(venus    = new Planet(sun,108160000,  12104, 'orange', 224, "Venus", 0.006772));
  stuff.push(earth    = new Planet(sun,149600000, 12756, 'blue', 365, 'Earth', 0.0167086));
  stuff.push(mun      = new Moon(earth, 385000, 3474, 'white', 30, 'The Moon', 0.05));
  stuff.push(mars     = new Planet(sun,227990000,  6792, 'red', 687, 'Mars', 0.0934));
  stuff.push(ab1 = new Rings(sun,374000000, 299200000,374000000, 299200000, 'brown'));
   stuff.push(ab2 = new Rings(sun, 418880000, 388960000, 418880000, 388960000, 'tan' ));
   stuff.push(ab3 = new Rings(sun,  493680000, 448800000,  493680000, 448800000, 'lightgreen'));
  stuff.push(jupiter  = new Planet(sun,778360000, 142984, 'red', 4332, "Jupiter", 0.0489));
  stuff.push(io       = new Moon(jupiter, 421800, 3645, 'white', 1.77, "Io", 0.0041));
  stuff.push(europa   = new Moon(jupiter, 671100, 3121, 'white', 3.5, "Europa", 0.0094));
  stuff.push(ganymede = new Moon(jupiter, 1070400, 5268, 'white', 7.15, "Ganymede", 0.0011));
  stuff.push(callisto = new Moon(jupiter, 1882700, 4820, 'white', 16.69, "Callisto", 0.0074));
  stuff.push(saturn   = new Planet(sun,1433500000, 120536, 'yellow', 10759, 'Saturn', 0.0565));
  stuff.push(satRings = new Rings(saturn, 180000*30, 66900*30, 480000*30, 74500*30, 255));
  stuff.push(uranus   = new Planet(sun, 2869000000, 50724, 'grey', 30685, "Uranus", 0.0461));
  stuff.push(urRings  = new Rings(uranus, 51170,51149,51249,51149 , 255));
  stuff.push(neptune  = new Planet(sun, 4497100000, 49244, 'grey', 60189, "Neptune", 0.01));
  stuff.push(nepRings = new Rings(neptune, 62934,42900,62930,40900 , 255));
}

function mouseClicked() {
  stopper === 1 ? stopper = 0 : stopper = 1;
  console.log(stopper);
}




function draw() {
  let pointer = window.innerHeight/2 + window.scrollY;
  let blurb = '';
  console.log(pointer);
  blurbSetter();
  background(0);
  stuff.forEach(thing => thing.show());
  textSize(50);
  fill(255);
  text("Erik's Final", 20, 50);
  textSize(18);
  text("A scale model of our solar system. \n 1 pixel = 10000km scale, \n and orbital distances have been further divided by 60. \n Orbital eccentricities are normalized along the vertical axis for viewability, \n and orbital periods have been accelerated equally. \n Click to pause at any time.", 20, 68);
  text(Math.floor(pointer) *scale*60 + " KM ----------- \n\n" + blurb, 20, pointer - 20);

  function blurbSetter(){
    if(pointer <= 650){
      blurb = 'The Inner Solar System: \n Home to your favorite elevated primates, \n the Inner Solar System harbors the \'Goldilocks Zone\',\n the area where the suns rays do not scorch the earth,\n and also still keep us from freezing. \nIt is the only area where carbon based life can flourish.';
    }else if(pointer > 650 && pointer < 1600){
      blurb = 'The Asteroid Belts: \n Home to the dwarf planet Ceres, \nour Asteroid Belt is divided into three distinct bands. \nBetween each band, the resonant frequency of Jupiter\'s \nimmense gravity well has caused orbits to destabilize, \nit\'s victims most often falling into the sun';
    }else if(pointer > 1600 && pointer < 3000){
      blurb = 'Though only the 4 largest are represented here, \nJupiter is home to more than 70 Moons!\n These 4 were discovered by Galileo Galilei, \nthe inventor of the modern refracting telescope, in 1609.';
    }else if(pointer > 3000 && pointer < 4800){
      blurb = 'Saturn\'s rings are its most distinctive feature, \nvisible from hundreds of millions of kilometers away. \nHowever, they are less than 10 meters thick! \nIf saturn was the size of a basketball, \nits rings would be over 100 times \nthinner than a single sheet of paper!';
    }if(pointer > 4800 && pointer < 7800){
      blurb = 'You might think there isn\'t much out this far, \nand for the most part you\'re right, but there is one major thing. \nThe Solar Wind, a constant stream of radiation and particles \nour sun is shedding, can still be felt out here. \nNASA has even designed deep space probes that utilize \nsolar sails instead of traditional engines, \nriding the wind like the seafaring explorers of history.';
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, but worst case scenario I just have to give up my idea that this would be to scale.

Comment: The HTML5 canvas element has issues when it is large. Would it be possible for you to use something like https://github.com/zenozeng/p5.js-svg , allowing you to use svg which handles large sizes better?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just have a canvas that is the width of the browser and have some way to scroll the contents of the canvas, like using arrow keys or something?

Comment: Please inform your teacher that Processing.js is no longer a maintained project, and I archived it at the start of December 2018. New projects and assignments should not be using it anymore. That said, SVG is by far the better solution here, which can take advantage of the browser's built in rendering system based on simple `<g transform>` elements. Using a canvas will be horribly slow (unless it's a webgl canvas, but then you have to deal with cameras and things get rather more complicated than they need to be)